# Counting vowels using switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I tried to design a program which counts the vowels in a sentence.

In my code, I used a `foreach` statement with the `if/else if` statement. I would like to convert these line of code using the `switch` statement
but I'm not really sure where to go. Do I need to add a new method? I would appreciate your help.

This is what I tried so far: I checked this one is very wrong. The `case 1` for example needs to have a constant. I'm not sure what constant shall I use here.

```
foreach (char v in yourSentence)
{
    switch (v)
    {
    case 1: 
        (v==ch1); 
        counta++; 
        j++; 
        break;

    case 2: 
        (v==ch2); 
        counte++; 
        j++; 
        break;
    case 3: 
        (v==ch3); 
        counti++; 
        j++; 
        break;
    case 4: 
        (v==ch4); 
        counto++; 
        j++; 
        break;
    case 5: 
        (v==ch3); 
        counti++; 
        j++; 
        break;             
    }
}
```

Another question:  I tried to change the color of the display text in the listBox. Is that possible to have different colors? What I also tried here is the first 5 (`listBox1.Items.Add`) are violet. And the sum of the (`listBox1.Items.Add`) is blue. But it seems that it didn't change. Did I miss something here?

```
private void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string yourSentence;
    yourSentence = textBoxVowels.Text.ToLower().Trim();

    char ch1 = 'a';
    char ch2 = 'e';
    char ch3 = 'i';
    char ch4 = 'o';
    char ch5 = 'u';

    int counta = 0;
    int counte = 0;
    int counti = 0;
    int counto = 0;
    int countu = 0;

    int j = counta + counte + counti + counto + countu;



    foreach (char v in yourSentence)
    {
        if (v == ch1) { counta++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch2) { counte++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch3) { counti++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch4) { counto++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch5) { countu++; j++; }
    }

    listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + counta.ToString().Trim() + " a's in the sentence");
    listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + counte.ToString().Trim() + " e's in the sentence");
    listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + counti.ToString().Trim() + " i's in the sentence");
    listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + counto.ToString().Trim() + " o's in the sentence");
    listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + countu.ToString().Trim() + " u's in the sentence");
    listBox1.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Violet;

    listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + j.ToString().Trim() + " vowels in the sentence");
    listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
}


private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxVowels.Text = null;
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I think the suggestion given by Noldorin would only give you the value of your j variable, not of counta, counte, etc.

Comment: As you have already selected an answer, I would create a new question detailing the specifics of your event question. If you're still trying to make multi-colored list items, I would make a separate question for that, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how 'switch/case' works. Just change them to this:

```
case 'a': 
     counta++; 
     j++; 
     break;
```

Case needs a constant value that should be compared to the current character.

Answer (score 9):

Or just simplify the whole problem by using a bit of [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx). :)

```
public static int CountVowels(this string value)
{
    const string vowels = "aeiou";
    return value.Count(chr => vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(chr)));
}
```

The [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) extension method is particularly well suited to this task. Also, notice the use of a string of all vowels to check each character - much simpler than a switch statement.

Note: It seems I missed the fact that you want to count each vowel individually. In this case, the LINQ becomes a bit more complicated (at least if you want to do it efficiently), but I shall leave that as an exercise for you. Regardless, a switch statement is probably a good way to learn the basics of C#.

---

Since you're probably curious about the switch statement anyway, the following code uses the correct syntax:

```
foreach (var chr in sentence)
{
    switch (chr) 
    {
        case 'a':
            ...
            break;
        case 'e':
            ...
            break;
        case 'i':
            ...
            break;
        case 'o':
            ...
        case 'u':
            ...
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: if I simplify it like your given example, which one do I still include in my code?

Comment: First part is OK, but will only give the total number of vowels (and is probably not suited to learn the language). Second part is wrong: case needs a constant.

Comment: @Martin: which part do you mean? You mean my code above? Or the one which uses the LINQ?

Comment: @Noldorin: thanks for the advice. I tried the first code you gave and I'm getting an error. Which part of my code will I retain? thanks

Comment: If you're not using .NET 3.5, the extension method I gave won't work. I recommend you just try and get the switch statement working well first.

Comment: @Noldorin: Yes I'm using it. The switch statement already works

Comment: @tintincute: Well for the extension method, you'll need to define it and use it in a certain way. It's quite simple though. See the MSDN page on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: Adding more vowels to the constant will support some other european languages :

const string vowels = "aáàeéèiíìóòouúù";

Comment: Note that this will not consider `I` a vowel on computers with turkish locale. Use `ToLowerInvariant`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more advanced solution:

```
public static Dictionary<char, int> CountLetters(string value, string letters)
{
    var counts = letters.ToDictionary(c => c.ToString(), c => 0, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    var groups = from c in value
                 let s = c.ToString()
                 where counts.ContainsKey(s)
                 group s by s;

    foreach(var g in groups)
        counts[g.Key] = g.Count();

    return counts;
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
var letterCounts = CountLetters(yourSentence, "aeiou");

int countA = letterCounts["a"];
int countE = letterCounts["e"];
int countI = letterCounts["i"];
int countO = letterCounts["o"];
int countU = letterCounts["u"];

int total = countA + countE + countI + countO + countU;
```

**Update:** Just realized that a `StringComparer` won't work for `char` keys. Switching to `string` key - not as efficient as `char`, but easier than writing a case-insensitive `char` comparer. I prefer the comparer approach to doing some sort of ToLower/ToUpper on everything dictionary-related.

Comment: He's using a Dictionary (aka map, aka associative array) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: Do you think I can also use array here in my code? Thanks for the link

Comment: An array can only be indexed with a positional integer. The benefit of using a dictionary is that you can efficiently access elements using an arbitrary* key (like a char or string). There are certainly solutions using arrays, but the general consensus here seems to favor a dictionary approach. (* arbitrary within some important constraints)

Comment: @dahlbyk: I'll try this and see if it works. Thanks for the input.I'm looking now how to have the event works

Answer (score 2):

Please also check the other answers to your questions for many helpful tips. I'm just rewriting your first piece of example code from your question to probably let it do what you mean:

```
foreach (char v in yourSentence)
{
    switch (v)
    {
        case 'a': counta++; j++; break;
        case 'e': counte++; j++; break;
        case 'i': counti++; j++; break;
        case 'o': counto++; j++; break;
        case 'u': countu++; j++; break;
    }
}
```

You seem to want to increase one of the `{ counta, counte, counti, counto, countu }` variables for the five specific vowels using the switch (right?) and also increase the `j` variable for each of the vowels.

Having given this answer, I would personally do something different altogether. Like the LINQ example given by Noldorin. Or something like this, as perhaps suggested by cherryalpha:

```
// create dictionary
var counts = new Dictionary<char,int>();

// initialize it for the vowels
foreach (char v in "aeiuo")
{
    counts.Add(v, 0);
}

// count all characters in sentence
foreach (char v in yourSentence) {
    if ( counts.ContainsKey(v) ) {
        // increase count for known characters
        counts[v]++;                        
    } else {
        // add new count for characters not seen previously
        counts.Add(v,1);
    }
}

// calculate your total number of vowels
j = counts['a'] + counts['e'] + counts['i'] + counts['o'] + counts['u'];
```

Quick warning, just in case: You would need a `using System.Collection.Generic` at the top of your source file that contains this code to make sure the generic Dictionary is known by its short name.

(And be aware that this code will not only give you vowel counts, but counts for all the other characters in `yourSentence` as well.)

Comment: @peSHIr: the code of Noldorin I can't have it work. I think I miss something. I'm not familiar with this one but I would love to try it out.

Comment: @tintincute: Make sure you are using .NET Framework 3.5 and include a "using System.LINQ" at the top of your source file, or the LINQ suggestion will never work.

Comment: @peSHIr: yes I'm using it: I can see at the top of my source file:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

Answer (score 1):

```
const string VOWELS = "aeiou";
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var q = from ch in str
        where VOWELS.Contains(ch)
        group ch by ch into g
        select g;
var dict = q.ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, _ => _.Count());
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand this coding.that means i still have a lot to learn. but thanks for sharing anyway,

Comment: THis code is LINQ, which makes life a whole lot easier. It is in the .NET Framework 3.5 release. (visual studio 2008). It allows you to query arbitrary collections of objects (and a string is a 'collection' of characters), or xml, or sql, etc.

Comment: @Colin: I think it is. But it's quite to understand haven't learned yet the data type "var" -(variable). not really sure how it works but I'd love to look at it a reference later.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar kind of problem in an interview. But I had to show my result in a level control instead of listbox control ... so i solved this problem like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EnterString;
    EnterString = TextBox1.Text;
    char ch1 = 'a';
    char ch2 = 'e';
    char ch3 = 'i';
    char ch4 = 'o';
    char ch5 = 'u';

    int counta = 0;
    int counte = 0;
    int counti = 0;
    int counto = 0;
    int countu = 0;
    char ch6 = 'A';
    char ch7 = 'E';
    char ch8 = 'I';
    char ch9 = 'O';
    char ch10 = 'U';

    int countA = 0;
    int countE = 0;
    int countI = 0;
    int countO = 0;
    int countU = 0;


    int j = counta + counte + counti + counto + countu + countA + countE + countI + countO + countU;

    foreach (char v in EnterString)
    {
        if (v == ch1) { counta++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch2) { counte++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch3) { counti++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch4) { counto++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch5) { countu++; j++; }
    }
    foreach (char v in EnterString)
    {
        if (v == ch6) { countA++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch7) { countE++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch8) { countI++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch9) { countO++; j++; }

        else if (v == ch10) { countU++; j++; }
    }

    Label1.Text = j.ToString();
}
```