# Counting number of vowels in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox where the user enters a random string. I want to count the number of vowels(A,E,I,O,U) in the string and show th results in the labelcontrol.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string EnterString;
        EnterString = TextBox1.Text;
        char ch1 = 'a';
        char ch2 = 'e';
        char ch3 = 'i';
        char ch4 = 'o';
        char ch5 = 'u';

        int counta = 0;
        int counte = 0;
        int counti = 0;
        int counto = 0;
        int countu = 0;
        char ch6 = 'A';
        char ch7 = 'E';
        char ch8 = 'I';
        char ch9 = 'O';
        char ch10 = 'U';

        int countA = 0;
        int countE = 0;
        int countI = 0;
        int countO = 0;
        int countU = 0;

        //const string vowels = "aeiou";
        /* return value.Count(chr => vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(chr)));
         return Value.Count()*/
        int j = counta + counte + counti + counto + countu + countA + countE + countI + countO + countU;

        foreach (char v in EnterString)
        {
            if (v == ch1) { counta++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch2) { counte++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch3) { counti++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch4) { counto++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch5) { countu++; j++; }
        }
        foreach (char v in EnterString)
        {
            if (v == ch6) { countA++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch7) { countE++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch8) { countI++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch9) { countO++; j++; }

            else if (v == ch10) { countU++; j++; }
        }

        Label1.Text = j.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Your caps lock got stuck

Comment: regex would be easier i'm thinking

Comment: How do you define a vowel? Only the 5 ones used in English, or the vowels used in other langs too?

Comment: [Please learn how to properly ask questions here.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/1228)

Comment: Why did you comment out the `const string vowels = "aeiou";
return value.Count(chr => vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(chr)));` part? That's a perfectly fine solution. (Excluding culture issues)

Comment: hey guys i am totally new to this forum...common dont make my grammar such an issue...can you help me in code..if not then dont give such comments...

Comment: @Bijay: Please read Will's comment. If you want people to put effort into answering your question, please put just as much effort into asking it.

Comment: I know no forum where writing everything using capital letters is considered good style.

Comment: common guys i am new here..and i am a beginner. so dont knew the rule..sorry anyway..

Comment: @CodeInChaos i cant understand how to show the result in labelcontrol. so i did it in a long process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this in your code:

```
const string vowels = "aeiou";
return value.Count(chr => vowels.Contains(char.ToLower(chr)));
```

That works, at least if your culture is US. So no idea why you commented it out in favor of the current monstrosity.

On a [Turkish locale](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html) it will fail because the lower case of `I` is not `i` but `ı` (undotted). So if you define vowels as `aeiouAEIOU` you should use `ToLowerInvariant`.

But if you want to include other vowels (like `Ä`) I have no idea how to do that except by listing all the characters.

Full implementation:

```
int CountVowels(string value)
{
    const string vowels = "aeiou";
    return value.Count(chr => vowels.Contains(char.ToLowerInvariant(chr)));
}
```

Looks like you got the good code part from:
[Counting vowels using switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187799/counting-vowels-using-switch/1187816#1187816)

Comment: Make it super multi-cultural and use ToLowerInvariant!

Comment: That deals with one issue, but not with the issue that some languages have additional vowels. And in other languages vowels are no concept that applies to their written language (Chinese for example doesn't use an alphabet based writing)

Comment: @CodeInChaos Hi i dont have these code in my application...my code is woring good but i want to minimize it means less code..can you help me.

Comment: These two lines were part of the code in the OP. You just commented them out.

Comment: i am a beginner, so i am learning how to code in effective way..and i want to insert a string in English language... so help me to learn..!!!!

Comment: he did help you, read his answer ... he replaced your code with 2 lines of cod eyou had already written and commented out.

Answer (score 2):

```
int vowel = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the string:");
        string main = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < main.Length ; j++)
        {
            if (main[j] == 'a' || main[j] == 'A' || main[j] == 'e' || main[j] == 'E' || main[j] == 'i' || main[j] == 'I' || main[j] == 'o' || main[j] == 'O' || main[j] == 'u' || main[j] == 'U')
            {
                vowel++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Number of vowels in sentence is :"+ vowel);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Try to explain what your code does and how it differs from the code in the question. It's much easier for everyone to learn that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please input your text: ")
    mystring = Console.ReadLine
    For i = 1 To mystring.Length
        Console.Write((mystring(i - 1)) & ",")
        isItAVowel = False
        If mystring(i - 1) = "a" Or mystring(i - 1) = "A" Then isItAVowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "e" Or mystring(i - 1) = "E" Then isItAVowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "i" Or mystring(i - 1) = "I" Then isItAVowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "o" Or mystring(i - 1) = "O" Then isItAVowel = True
        If mystring(i - 1) = "u" Or mystring(i - 1) = "U" Then isItAVowel = True
        If isItAVowel Then
```

This could help good luck

Answer (score 0):

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        string EnterString;
        EnterString = textBox1.Text;
        const string vowels = "aeiou";
        label1.Text = EnterString.Count(myString => vowels.Contains(char.ToLowerInvariant(myString))).ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
    char[] sentence = new char[100];

    int i, vowels = 0, consonants = 0, special = 0, n;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Length of the sentence  \n");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sentence[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
    }
    for (i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if ((sentence[i] == 'a' || sentence[i] == 'e' || sentence[i] ==
        'i' || sentence[i] == 'o' || sentence[i] == 'u') ||
        (sentence[i] == 'A' || sentence[i] == 'E' || sentence[i] ==
        'I' || sentence[i] == 'O' || sentence[i] == 'U'))
        {
            vowels = vowels + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            consonants = consonants + 1;
        }
        if (sentence[i] == 't' || sentence[i] == '\0' || sentence[i] == ' ')
        {
            special = special + 1;
        }
    }

    consonants = consonants - special;
    Console.WriteLine("No. of vowels {0}", vowels);
    Console.WriteLine("No. of consonants {0}", consonants);
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std;    
int main()    
{    
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    set<char> vowels = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        int c = 0;
        cin >> s;
        for(char i : s)
            if(vowels.find(i) != vowels.end())
                ++c;
        cout << c << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string vowelList = ("aeiouAEIOU");
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int vowelCount = 0;

        string main = textBox1.Text;  /or Console.ReadLine();

        while (j < main.Length)

        {
            while (i < vowelList.Length)
            {
                if (main[j] == vowelList[i])
                {
                    vowelCount++;
                }

                i++; 
            }

            j = j + 1;
            i = 0;
        }

        label1.Text = ("Number of vowels in sentence is :" + vowelCount);  /or Console.Writeline ("Number of vowels in sentence is:  " + vowelCount
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
string=input("Enter string:")
vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")
for letter in string:
    if letter in vowels:
        count += 1
print("Count of the vowels is:")
print(count)
```

Comment: It is helpful for the OP if you post a couple lines about what you are doing instead of a simple code block!